# How to generate an Output

Tags: arcpy, layers, merge, multi-values

There are a few similar Questions which mention this issue but sadly not helping me out with my problem.

I want to generate an output out of my tool but am not sure which phrase and Datatype to use.

Additionally while importing the Script to ArcMap it just says failed to execute without further information. In Pycharm its stopping at the processing of merge and I am not sure where the mistakes are.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

# Local variables:
Streets_ND = "Streets_ND"
Route = "Route"
Route__2_ = Route
Stores_to_merge = "Stores_to_merge"
MainStore = "MainStore"
Stores = "Stores"
Stores_select_shp = "Stores_select"
Route__3_ = Route__2_
Solve_Succeeded = "false"
Route__4_ = Route__3_
Route_Directions_html = "Directions.lyr"

# Process: Make Route Layer
arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(Streets_ND, "Route", "Minutes", "USE_INPUT_ORDER", "PRESERVE_BOTH", "USE_TIMEWINDOWS", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "Oneway;RestrictedTurns", "USE_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "")

# Process: Select_MainStore
arcpy.Select_analysis(Stores_to_merge, MainStore, "OBJECTID = 1")

# Process: Merge MainStore+Stores_to_merge
arcpy.Merge_management([Stores_to_merge, MainStore], Stores) 

# Process: Select_createPick-List
multival = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # 'Store_1;Store_2;Store_3'
vals = multival.split(";")

where_stub = """"NAME" IN ({})"""
Stores = ','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in vals])
where = where_stub.format(Stores)

arcpy.Select_analysis(Stores, Stores_select_shp, where)

# Process: Add Locations
arcpy.AddLocations_na(Route, "Stops", Stores_select_shp, "Name Name #", "5000 Meters", "", "Streets SHAPE;Streets_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "INCLUDE", "Streets #;Streets_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Solve
arcpy.Solve_na(Route__2_, "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "", "")

# Process: Directions
arcpy.Directions_na(Route__3_, "HTML", Route_Directions_html, "Miles", "REPORT_TIME", "Minutes", "en", "NA Desktop", "")

arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(Route_Directions_html, "Directions.lyr")
```

Comment: I found a Solution for the Output by defining it through a "GetParametersAsText"-phrase in the directions process. But still don't know why its not running...

Comment: I think it's hard to figure out what is your question. Could you please add more details such as how do you create a custom script tool, what are the parameters, what messages do you get when doing X and X. Without this, it's really hard to help.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  As @AlexTereshenkov commented above, please **[edit]** your question to give details about your specific problem, including any error messages in full.  Include details about what you're trying to achieve, and what actually happens when you run your code.